# Como posso percorrer este JSON e recuperar a lista de Movies?

Tags: android, json, retrofit

Estou com dificuldades em percorrer este JSON e extrair os dados do Array "movies".

Segue JSON: (https://yts.ag/api/v2/list_movies.json)

O erro é este:

> java.lang.NullPointerException na linha for (Movies m : catalogoMovies.movies)

Segue um trecho do código:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(MovieService.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    MovieService service = retrofit.create(MovieService.class);
    final Call<CatalogoMovies> requestCatalogo = service.listCatalog();

    requestCatalogo.enqueue(new Callback<CatalogoMovies>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<CatalogoMovies> call, Response<CatalogoMovies> response) {
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + response.code());
            } else {
                CatalogoMovies catalogoMovies = response.body();
                for (Movies m : catalogoMovies.movies) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "TITLE: " + m.title);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<CatalogoMovies> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + t.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

**Log de Erro**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.example.luciano.saiufilme, PID: 12116
   java.lang.NullPointerException
       at com.example.luciano.saiufilme.HomeActivity$1.onResponse(HomeActivity.java:40)
       at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**CatalogoMovies**

```
public class CatalogoMovies {

     public List<Movies> movies;

}
```

Comment: Você configurou a permissão para acesso a internet ? [documentação](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html)

Comment: Sim, já adicionei essa permissão no AndroidManifest.

Comment: edita a pergunta e coloca o log de erro gerado.

Comment: Editei.
Como disse no início do post, o erro é java.lang.NullPointerException na linha for (Movies m : catalogo.movies) {

Comment: Veja se pode ajudar [guj.com.br](http://respostas.guj.com.br/51579-retrofit-erro-de-nullpointerexception)

Comment: Como está seu objeto `CatalogoMovies ` ?

Comment: Teria como colocar na sua pergunta o conteúdo de CatalogoMovies?

Comment: Dá uma olhada, já editei.

Answer (score 2):

Este `NullPointerException` ocorre pois dentro de `CatalogoMovies` não há uma Lista de `Movie`!

A estrutura dos Objetos está diferente do `JSON` que você adicionou no [link](https://yts.ag/api/v2/list_movies.json).

A Lista está dentro do de `data`:

```
{ // OBJETO CatalogoMovies
    "status": "ok",
    "status_message": "Query was successful",
    "data": {            // OBEJTO DATA
        "movie_count": 6334,
        "limit": 20,
        "page_number": 1,
        "movies": [{     // AQUI ESTÁ A LISTA
......
```

Para facilitar (e se está utilizando o Android Studio), sugiro utilizar um **plugin** para gerar estas classes automaticamente.

Para instalar: 
Menu superior:

> File> Settings

Na Janela que será exibida, procure no menu lateral:

> Plugins

Pesquise por: **Json2Pojo**

Instale o plugin, e reinicie o Android Studio!

Feito isto,copie o `Json` completo, clique com o botão direito sobre o pacote que irá adicionar as classes,e vá em

> New> Generate POJO from JSON

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Cole seu JSON e informe um nome para classe:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Obs.**: Se ocorrer um erro com a `tag @Generated("net.hexar.json2pojo")`  remova o sem problemas.

Este plugin irá gerar as classes automaticamente, evitando este tipo de erro.

[LINK DO PLUGIN](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8533-json2pojo)

[LINK SOBRE INSTALAR PLUGIN ANDROID STUDIO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30617408/how-to-install-plugin-in-android-studio/30617737)

Comment: Oi Thiago, fiz o que você recomendou.
Porém agora o erro é outro: 
ERROR: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Comment: É extamente o mesmo JSON?

Comment: use este endereço para validar o retorno https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Sim, exatamente o mesmo.

Comment: Estranho, ele diz que ao invés de iniciar uma lista, está iniciando um objeto! fiz um teste com o link aqui e funcionou! Pode editar a pergunta e colocar como está fazendo agora? se possível adicionar o objeto que possui o data tbm!

Comment: Oi Thiago, eu vou te passar o link do app no Github. 
Já estou sem saber como resolver isso, rsrs

https://github.com/luciano01/AppFilmes

Comment: em vez de Call<List<CatalogoMovies>>  coloque Call<CatalogoMovies>

Comment: Fiz essa alteração, após recuperar o corpo desse JSON, como devo prosseguir para pegar os dados?

Estou fazendo assim, mas tem erro.

`CatalogoMovies catalogoMovies = (CatalogoMovies) response.body();
                    for(Data data : catalogoMovies.getData()){
                        for(Movie movie : data.getMovies()){
                            Log.i(TAG, "ERROR: " + movie.getTitle());
                        }
                    }`

Comment: UFA! Consegui.
O trecho de código no meu último comentário estava errado.

Código correto:

'CatalogoMovies catalogoMovies = response.body();
                    for(Movie data : catalogoMovies.getmData().getMovies()){
                        Log.i(TAG, "TITLE: " + data.getTitle());
                    }'

Comment: Thiago, muito obrigado pela ajuda. Graças a sua paciência e colaboração consegui resolver o meu problema. Agradeço imensamente. Abraço.